# why cannot I assign a newly allocated byte array to a variable with []byte as type?

Tags: arrays, memory-management, types, go, allocation

I am trying to declare a variable of type array with unspecified size `[]byte` and then filling it with an allocated array of size `256` as follows:

```
var buf []byte
buf = new([256]byte)
```

Unfortunately, it does not work. The compile error returned is the following:

```
cannot use *new([256]byte) (type [256]byte) as type []byte in assignment
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to assign an array to a slice, which won't work (see "[Go Slices: usage and internals](http://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals)")

To make a slice instead, use:

```
var buf []byte
buf = make([]byte, 256)
```

The difference:

> An array variable denotes the entire array; it is not a pointer to the first array element (as would be the case in C).
>   This means that when you assign or pass around an array value you will make a copy of its contents. (To avoid the copy you could pass a pointer to the array, but then that's a pointer to an array, not an array.)
>   One way to think about arrays is as a sort of struct but with indexed rather than named fields: a fixed-size composite value.

Versus:

> A slice is a descriptor of an array segment.
>   It consists of a pointer to the array, the length of the segment, and its capacity (the maximum length of the segment).

---

If you want to create an array (an assign it to an array), that would have been:

```
var buf [256]byte
buf = [256]byte{}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the newly allocated array as a slice by slicing it like this:

```
var slice []byte = buf[:]
```

This creates slice as a slice that is backed by the array buf.